# Jquery - Find closest previous <tr> by class at checkbox clicking. the checkbox is inside a <td>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, html-table

I need to find the previous and closest element (".table-primary") to the td that contain the input ("checkbox").

If i check the checkbox inside the "David" row it should find the "Patricia" row element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="max-width: 36px;"></th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Surname</th>
          <th scope="col">Work</th>
          <th scope="col">Country</th>
          <th scope="col">Birthday</th>
          <th scope="col">Hobbyes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Mark</td>
          <td class="surname">White</td>
          <td class="work">Lawyer</td>
          <td class="country">USA</td>
          <td class="birthday">26/05/1993</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Tennis, Music</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Laura</td>
          <td class="childage">5</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Maurice</td>
          <td class="childage">10</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Bryan</td>
          <td class="childage">2</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Patricia</td>
          <td class="surname">Mallon</td>
          <td class="work">Manager</td>
          <td class="country">Germany</td>
          <td class="birthday">05/07/1976</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Mode, Cooking, Reading</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">David</td>
          <td class="childage">8</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Wuei</td>
          <td class="surname">Zong</td>
          <td class="work">Marketing</td>
          <td class="country">China</td>
          <td class="birthday">01/01/1945</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Bricolage, Manual Work, Sleep</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="childname">Philips</td>
            <td class="childage">12</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="childname">Alice</td>
            <td class="childage">22</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have already tried using closest() e prev(). But it doesn't seem to work, I don't understand why.

Comment: What was the code you tried?  Might just be a simple typo. What didn't work? Did the event run? Did you add it as an event?   `$(this).closest("tr").prev()` would give you the Patricia row from inside a checkbox event

Comment: He want to get the nearest previous `tr` with class `.table-primary`, not the previous `tr`.

Comment: Your last two rows appear to be within another row

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, @freedomn-m after posting the question I solved in the way you advised me.

Comment: Be warned that `.prev()` is *always* the previous row.  If you want the previous "parent"/"header"/"primary" row then you need @CuongLeNgoc's approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to do that:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.form-check-input', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').prevAll('.table-primary').first().text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="max-width: 36px;"></th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Surname</th>
          <th scope="col">Work</th>
          <th scope="col">Country</th>
          <th scope="col">Birthday</th>
          <th scope="col">Hobbyes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Mark</td>
          <td class="surname">White</td>
          <td class="work">Lawyer</td>
          <td class="country">USA</td>
          <td class="birthday">26/05/1993</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Tennis, Music</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Laura</td>
          <td class="childage">5</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Maurice</td>
          <td class="childage">10</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Bryan</td>
          <td class="childage">2</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Patricia</td>
          <td class="surname">Mallon</td>
          <td class="work">Manager</td>
          <td class="country">Germany</td>
          <td class="birthday">05/07/1976</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Mode, Cooking, Reading</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">David</td>
          <td class="childage">8</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Wuei</td>
          <td class="surname">Zong</td>
          <td class="work">Marketing</td>
          <td class="country">China</td>
          <td class="birthday">01/01/1945</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Bricolage, Manual Work, Sleep</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="childname">Philips</td>
            <td class="childage">12</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="childname">Alice</td>
            <td class="childage">22</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: I upvote this post, better aproach than mine, takeme about 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You need use **parent** function and after make a loop of **prev** elements, running the **hasClass** function for meet the condition and after access to name class.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  
  if($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).parent().parent().parent().is("tbody")){
  
  let p = $(this).parent().parent();
  
  while(!$(p).hasClass("table-primary")){
  
    p = $(p).prev();
    
    
    
  }
  
  console.log($(p).children(".name").text());
  
  }
  
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="max-width: 36px;"></th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Surname</th>
          <th scope="col">Work</th>
          <th scope="col">Country</th>
          <th scope="col">Birthday</th>
          <th scope="col">Hobbyes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Mark</td>
          <td class="surname">White</td>
          <td class="work">Lawyer</td>
          <td class="country">USA</td>
          <td class="birthday">26/05/1993</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Tennis, Music</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Laura</td>
          <td class="childage">5</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Maurice</td>
          <td class="childage">10</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">Bryan</td>
          <td class="childage">2</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Patricia</td>
          <td class="surname">Mallon</td>
          <td class="work">Manager</td>
          <td class="country">Germany</td>
          <td class="birthday">05/07/1976</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Mode, Cooking, Reading</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="childname">David</td>
          <td class="childage">8</td>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td class="docRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="name">Wuei</td>
          <td class="surname">Zong</td>
          <td class="work">Marketing</td>
          <td class="country">China</td>
          <td class="birthday">01/01/1945</td>
          <td class="hobbyes">Bricolage, Manual Work, Sleep</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="childname">Philips</td>
            <td class="childage">12</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="fileRow"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="childname">Alice</td>
            <td class="childage">22</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```